# Why is $(5\sqrt{5p}-3\sqrt{5q})(5\sqrt{5p}+3\sqrt{5q}) \equiv 5(5p-3q)(5p+3q)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

I was working on the difference of two squares, $125p^2-45q^2$

Writing my answer, $$(5\sqrt{5}p-3\sqrt{5}q)(5\sqrt{5}p+3\sqrt{5}q),$$ onto Pearson, I got a popup that said my answer was equivalent to the correct answer but in incorrect form. Apparently, the correct answer is $$5(5p-3q)(5p+3q).$$

Why is that? I'm failing to see the intuition here.

Comment: After your edit it is still wrong. You expression is not equivalent to the suggested answer.

Comment: Ah ugh, didn't catch that. I'm sleep deprived, sorry. I think I fixed it, let me know if it's still wrong.

Comment: I edited for you. To edit the title is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

$$125p^2-45q^2=5(25p^2-9q^2)=5(5p+3q)(5p-3q)$$
Your answer was incorrect because it should have been
$$125p^2-45q^2=(\sqrt{125}p^2+\sqrt{45}q^2)(\sqrt{125}p^2-\sqrt{45}q^2)=(5\sqrt{5}p+3\sqrt{5}q)(5\sqrt{5}p-3\sqrt{5}q)=5(5p+3q)(5p-3q)$$

Comment: That's how I've been doing it lately, but can you show how I can derive that when I get roots involved? This question is not asking how to get the correct answer, it's asking why the form of my answer is equivalent to the correct answer.

Comment: See my edit, I'm pretty sure your answer was actually incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Think like this:

$$
125p^2-45q^2= 5\cdot 5^2p^2- 5\cdot 3^2q^2= 5\big((5p)^2-(3q)^2\big)=5(5p-3q)(5p+3q)
$$

This way you skip dealing with those pesky squareroots.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not correct or Person's algebraic module is buggy.

Your supposed equivalent expression should be 
$$(5p\sqrt{5}-3q\sqrt{\color{red}{5}})(5p\sqrt{5}+3q\sqrt{\color{red}{5}})$$

**Edit after OP's edit:**

Note that

- $125p^2 = \left(5\sqrt{5}\cdot p\right)^2$
- $45q^2 = \left(3\sqrt{5}\cdot q\right)^2$

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo on my part. Pearson really is buggy, though.